# How to specify more than one DNS in resolvconf.conf?

Tags: dns, resolvconf

I am trying to make resolvconf prepend two additional nameservers to /etc/resolv.conf when run with "resolvconf -u".
My /etc/resolvconf.conf file is as follows:

```
# Configuration for resolvconf(8)
# See resolvconf.conf(5) for details

resolv_conf=/etc/resolv.conf
# If you run a local name server, you should uncomment the below line and
# configure your subscribers configuration files below.
name_servers=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1

# Mirror the Debian package defaults for the below resolvers
# so that resolvconf integrates seemlessly.
dnsmasq_resolv=/var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
pdnsd_conf=/etc/pdnsd.conf
unbound_conf=/var/cache/unbound/resolvconf_resolvers.conf
```

The problem emerges when I run the command "resolvconf -u", this is the output I get:

```
/sbin/resolvconf: 7: /etc/resolvconf.conf: 1.0.0.1: not found
/sbin/resolvconf: 7: /etc/resolvconf.conf: 1.0.0.1: not found
/sbin/resolvconf: 7: /etc/resolvconf.conf: 1.0.0.1: not found
/sbin/resolvconf: 7: /etc/resolvconf.conf: 1.0.0.1: not found
/sbin/resolvconf: 7: /etc/resolvconf.conf: 1.0.0.1: not found
/sbin/resolvconf: 7: /etc/resolvconf.conf: 1.0.0.1: not found
```

If I specify just ONE SINGLE DNS in the name_servers line it works fine. I also tried to wrap the DNS definitions with "", but it still doesn't accept them. I can't find anything about the correct syntax in the manual.

Comment: repeat the line `name_servers=x.x.x.x` for each DNS server you want to specify.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/sbin/resolvconf` is actually a shell script, and the configuration files are just sourced scripts, so the syntax you'll need is the same as with shell scripts:

```
name_servers="1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1"
```

Comment: Why is a simple example like this Not in the manpage? Would have saved me 5 minutes searching the internet